# Type casting between derived class and base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

If I have a base class that I declared it as a child class, and then added to a vector consisting of the base class, is there a way to cast that base class back to a child class, since I know that the "base" is in fact the child? For example:

```
class Libitem{
    //......
};

class Book : public Libitem{
    //......
}

int main{
    vector<Libitem> lib;
    Libitem book = Book();
    lib.push_back(book);
    Book b = static_cast<Book>(lib.at(0)); //this is wrong. Is there a way to do this correctly?
}
```

Am I doing my cast wrong or is their something that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: You are victim of object slicing. [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) To get polymorphic behaviour you will need to use pointers or references. Also read up on [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Comment: "since I know that the "base" is in fact the child?" thats not correct. The base is the child minus all fields that the child adds to the base